# How can I change a day's background color in the week view of Thunderbird calendar?

Tags: css, calendar, thunderbird

There are multiple examples for changing a day's background color in Thunderbird's calendar by adding CSS expressions to `userChrome.css`, e.g.

```css
.calendar-month-day-box-current-month[year="2023"][month="12"][day="25"] .calendar-month-day-box-list {
        background-color: var(--viewWeekendBackground)} !important;
}
```

But this only affects the views showing one month or multiple weeks.

How can I change a day's background color in the views showing a single day or a week?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to change the color of the current day's heading in week-view of Thunderbird (v115.8.1). Steps:

1. Hamburger Menu > Settings > scroll to Bottom > Config Editor > set 'toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets' = true
2. Hamburger Menu > Help > Troubleshooting Info > click 'about:Profiles' > 'default-release' > Root > Open Directory
3. Create new dir (if not exist): 'chrome'
4. Create new file (if not exist): 'userChrome.css'
5. Add the css:

```css
.day-column-today .day-column-heading {
  background-color: lightgreen !important;
}
```